# Finding a point on a straight line with DbGeography.Intersect()

Tags: c#, intersection, dbgeography

I am currently learning about DbGeography in C# and playing around with some functionality.

I have been trying to ascertain whether the `Intersects()` method will return true for a point lying on a straight line (represented as a LineString `DbGeography` object) if the point lies between the starting and end points.

So, my question is: Can the `[myPoint].Intersects([myLine])` method be trusted to tell me if myPoint lies on myLine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Intersects` method to determine whether a point lies on a line, as long as the point is within the bounding box of the line.

for example:

```
DbGeography myPoint = DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(10 10)", 4326);
DbGeography myLine = DbGeography.LineFromText("LINESTRING(0 0, 20 20)", 4326);

bool myPointIntersectsWithmyLine = myPoint.Intersects(myLine);
```

the variable `myPointIntersectsWithmyLine` should be true here since `myPoint` lies on `myline` object.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! By bounding box do you mean the range for the coordinate system being used?